# What function is M-. (for following functions through TAGs) bound to in emacs?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, emacs, ide, elisp

What function is M-. (for following functions through TAGs) bound to in emacs? I want to bind it to a shortcut (F2, for consistency with IDEs like RStudio and QtCreator).

Answer (score 2):

By default it's bound to `find-tag`. However, many modes rebind it to something more specific to a particular language.

You can find out what function a key sequence is bound to with `C-h k` (for `describe-key`) followed by the key sequence you're interested in. So in this case you would do `C-h k M-.`.

You can also use F1 in place of `C-h`, so `<f1> k M-.` should work too.